# TFS with external GITLAB build failures

Tags: tfs, gitlab

I'm trying to setup TFS 2015 update 4 with GitLab (CE11.1.4) external GIT Service endpoint in TFS.
When I access my GitLab server in the lab from a web browser, I use https, I get a not secure warning, but I click through it.
If I try and access the web page via http, I get redirected to the https page. Which make sense.

When I create the Service endpoint in TFS, I have entered the URL both ways, http and https. I get build failure with either configuration.

for `http://gitlab` I get the following error when trying to build:

> Syncing repository: my GitLab (Git) Starting clone
>   **LibGit2Sharp.LibGit2SharpException: Cross host redirect not allowed**

I will assume that is because I used the http instead of https.

My next test was to use `https://gitlab`, and that gave me this error:

> Syncing repository: my GitLab (Git) Starting clone
>   **LibGit2Sharp.LibGit2SharpException: failed to send request: The connection with the server was terminated abnormally**

Whats going on, I've searched the web and not really finding anything.

**Followup question:** When you create the Service endpoint, whats is going on under the TFS covers? Are we just storing the URL and the username and password to be used later on the fly during a build process?

Comment: Have you successfully configured the Service endpoint? Did you set proxy for your TFS?

Answer (score 0):

Just try to add the GitLab server URL (try both `http` and `https`) to your trust site in IE or any other browser, then try it again.

This also might be the SSL issue with your server, please reference this thread: https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/1524

Whatever you can refer to [Troubleshoot Build and Release](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/vsts/pipelines/troubleshooting?view=vsts#git) for the troubleshooting with the instruction with external git.

For the follow up question, you need to provide the URL and the username, password to create the service endpoint. The endpoint is just for creating a connection between external Git and TFS. Once the service endpoint is created then you can use it directly in your build/release process (Don't need to enter the username, password anymore). Just like using the internal repository within TFS itself...

Comment: Just to rule out issues with the certs in my home Lab, I decided to try the test on our production environment. 
I set up the Service Endpoint in TFS to use the https url, my gitlab user ID and my personal access token.

I got the flowing error:
Syncing repository: WPS GitLab (Git)
Starting clone
LibGit2Sharp.LibGit2SharpException: failed to send request: The connection with the server was terminated abnormally
at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Ensure.HandleError(Int32 result)
at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Proxy.git_clone(String url, String workdir, GitCloneOptions& opts)

Comment: Does the clone command want to use https transfer or SSH?  Maybe we are not configured for https

Comment: I had a thought so tried the following on my pc via git bash: $ git clone https://git-corp-p1.wpsic.com/0019247/CSAT_Test.git
Cloning into 'CSAT_Test'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://git-corp-p1.wpsic.com/0019247/CSAT_Test.git/': SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

Comment: Is there a step by step document to configure a build server for External Git in TFS? What are the prerequisites for making this work?

Comment: @PatDelaney No step by step documents, however you can refer to [Service connections for builds and releases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=vsts) and [External Git service connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=vsts#sep-extgit) for the configuration.  For the SSH problems please refer to [Use SSH key authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate?view=vsts) for details.